# How to select only non-numeric data from the mixed table

Tags: list-manipulation, data, filtering

Consider the following data:

```
data={{1,2,3},{2,3,4},{1,5,Some symbols},{00,230,Some other symbols}}
```

where "Some symbols" is something arbitrary (say, a long Mathematica's report about errors). Could you please tell me how to select only rows with symbols, such that

```
dataselected={{1,5,Some symbols},{00,230,Some other symbols}}
```

Comment: `DeleteCases[data, {__, _?NumberQ}]` ?

Comment: You might need `NumericQ` instead of `NumberQ`, if you also want to exclude things like `Sqrt[2]` (since `NumberQ[Sqrt[2]]` is `False`, but `NumericQ[Sqrt[2]]` is `True`.)

Comment: Note also that "symbols" in Mathematica lingo specifically refer to `Symbol`s, i.e. variables/names that can hold definitions, i.e. things that return `True` under `SymbolQ`. It seems like you simply want to remove non-numeric values as opposed to select for `Symbol`s. The general term for an arbitrary Mathematica expression would be, well, an "expression". maybe this is nitpicky, but I need to find SOME way to procrastinate, so